# Powershell: ForEach concatenates all values found into one and script fails

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to create a script which will detect all XLSX files in C:\Temp\ConversionCSV\ and convert them to CSV. It works fine when there is only one file in the folder.

However when there are 2 files, ForEach "concatenates" both FullName values into a single one before attempting the xlsx to csv conversion (apparently that's how it works). That causes the conversion to fail. I also tried ForEach-Object.

Is there any way to get the script to run on each item without grouping them first? Or an alternative? Can I just change the extension (that doesn't seem right)?

PS: I can't find the source of the original script anymore so can't credit the author.

SCRIPT:

```
cls
 Try {
      $Directory = "C:\temp\ConversionCSV\" 

      $ExcelFiles = (Get-ChildItem $Directory | Where Extension -Like .XLS* `
                                              | Select Name `
                                              | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders `
                                              | Out-String -ErrorAction Stop `
                                              ).trim() 


        #Files successfully detected:
        #C:\temp\ConversionCSV\copy.xlsx           
        #C:\temp\ConversionCSV\FinancialSample.xlsx


     Get-ChildItem $Repertoire | Select Name, Extension,  `
                                        BaseName, FullName, `
                                        Directory, DirectoryName `
                               | Where Extension -eq .XLSX `
                               | Out-String


      ForEach  ($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles) 

              {
                   $xlCSV               = 6  
                   $Excel               = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application 
                   $Excel.Visible       = $False
                   $Excel.displayalerts = $False
                   ##############################################################################

                   $FullName =  $Directory+(Get-Variable -scope Local `
                                           | Where Name -EQ 'ExcelFile' `
                                           | Select Value `
                                           | Format-table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize -Wrap `
                                           | Out-String -ErrorAction Stop).Trim()

                   Write-Host " `$FullName is $FullName"

                   ##############################################################################

                   $CSVfilename = ($FullName -Replace "XLSX", "CSV").Trim()

                   ##############################################################################

                   $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FullName) 
                   $Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV) 

                   ##############################################################################

                   $NewCSV=   Get-ChildItem $Directory | Select Name, Extension, ` 
                                                                BaseName, FullName, `
                                                                Directory,  DirectoryName `
                                                       | Where  Extension -eq .CSV `
                                                       | Out-String -ErrorAction Stop

                   ##############################################################################

                   #regionCloseExcel

                  $Excel.Quit()

                   If     (Get-Process Excel)

                          {Write-Host "Closing Excel" 
                           Stop-Process -Name Excel} 

                   ElseIf (!(Get-Process Excel))

                          {Write-Host "`n Excel not runnning."}

                   Else   {Write-Host "`n Unexpected event."}

                   #endregionCloseExcel

                 }

      }


 Catch   {
          Write-Host "`n---------------------ERROR--------------`n"
          $_.Exception
          }


 Finally {Write-Host "`n----------------------END---------------"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time to understand why you need to call for `Get-ChildItem $Repertoire` and have so much code to generate the `$FullName` of the Excel file.

Here is the simplified version of you code that works:

```
Try {
  $Directory = "C:\temp\"

  $ExcelFiles = (Get-ChildItem $Directory | Where Extension -Like ".XLS*")

  ForEach  ($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles) {

       # grab the FullName here -> no need to parse
       $FullName = $ExcelFile.FullName

       $xlCSV               = 6  
       $Excel               = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application 
       $Excel.Visible       = $False
       $Excel.displayalerts = $False

       ##############################################################################              

       Write-Host " `$FullName is $FullName"

       ##############################################################################

       $CSVfilename = ($FullName -Replace "XLSX", "CSV").Trim()

       ##############################################################################

       $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FullName) 
       $Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV) 

       ##############################################################################

       $Excel.Quit()

       If     (Get-Process Excel)

              {Write-Host "Closing Excel" 
               Stop-Process -Name Excel} 


       ElseIf (!(Get-Process Excel))

              {Write-Host "`n Excel not runnning."}


       Else   {Write-Host "`n Unexpected event."}

       #endregionCloseExcel

     }
}
Catch { Write-Host "n---------------------ERROR--------------n" $_.Exception }
Finally {Write-Host "`n----------------------END---------------"}
```

Comment: @Dragonthoughts: 
Thank you! I'm very rusty, I should have thought of that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: sorry I replied to the wrong person - thanks for your answer.